# How do I make it so that when my variable reaches a certain point, I have an alert popup saying something?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>John's Sustainability Clicker</title>
    <style>
    h1 { padding: 0; margin: 10px 0 0; }
        p { padding: 0; margin: 10px; }
    </style>
</head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        if (clicks = 50) {
         window.alert "You have made earth sustainable!"   
        } else {
            document.write " "
        }

    </script>

<div style="color:#AF7817">
    <center><h1 stlye="margin-bottom: 0 0 0 0"><p style="font-size:70px">My Sustainability Clicker</p></h1></center>
</div>

<div style="color:#2B65EC"> 
    <div class="game-object">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var clicks = 0;
            function updateClickCount() {
                document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML = clicks;
            }
        </script>
        <center><button type="button" onClick="clicks++;updateClickCount();" id="push">
           <p style="font-size:20px"><div style="color:#E238EC">Click me for Trees!</div></p></button></center>
   <center> <p style="font-size:20px"><div id="clickCount"></div></p></center>
    </div>
</div>    

<div style="color:#F70D1A">
   <center><p style="font-size:20px"><i><b>By: John Parkinham</i></b></p></center>
</div>

<center><input type="image" name="Cookie" value="Cookie" src="tree-clipart-tree_tiny_green_shaded.png" width="445px"/></center>

    </input>
```

My question is, how do I have it so that when my clicks variable reaches 50, I get an alert message pop up on screen? I don't know if I should use the if else command or if I should use something else.

Thanks
~John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, in thinking you will need an if statement.  But *where* do you need an if statement.  The current if (clicks = 50) has several issues.

First the single equals sign will assign the value 50 to the variable clicks.  To compare two values and then return a true or false value you need to use ==

Second this block of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (clicks = 50) {
     window.alert "You have made earth sustainable!"   
    } else {
        document.write " "
    }
</script>
```

Which will be run in your page before the variable clicks is first defined.  The correct place to be checking the value of clicks is after each time that value is updated in your updateClickCount function

```
function updateClickCount() {
    document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML = clicks;
    if(clicks == 50)
    {
        alert("hurray 50!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also recommend moving your increment of clicks from the onclick attribute into the function body of updateClickCount

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>John's Sustainability Clicker</title>
    <style>
    h1 { padding: 0; margin: 10px 0 0; }
        p { padding: 0; margin: 10px; }
    </style>
</head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            var clicks = 0;
            function updateClickCount() {
                 clicks++; 
                document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML = clicks;
                if (clicks == 50) {
                  alert( "You have made earth sustainable!");   
                } 
            }
        </script>

<div style="color:#AF7817">
    <center><h1 stlye="margin-bottom: 0 0 0 0"><p style="font-size:70px">My Sustainability Clicker</p></h1></center>
</div>

<div style="color:#2B65EC"> 
    <div class="game-object">

        <center><button type="button" onclick="updateClickCount();" id="push">
           <p style="font-size:20px"><div style="color:#E238EC">Click me for Trees!</div></p></button></center>
   <center> <p style="font-size:20px"><div id="clickCount"></div></p></center>
    </div>
</div>    

<div style="color:#F70D1A">
   <center><p style="font-size:20px"><i><b>By: John Parkinham</i></b></p></center>
</div>

<center><input type="image" name="Cookie" value="Cookie" src="tree-clipart-tree_tiny_green_shaded.png" width="445px"/></center>

    </input>
```

Edited...

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>John's Sustainability Clicker</title>
    <style>
    h1 { padding: 0; margin: 10px 0 0; }
        p { padding: 0; margin: 10px; }
    </style>
</head>

    <script type="text/javascript">



    </script>

<div style="color:#AF7817">
    <center><h1 stlye="margin-bottom: 0 0 0 0"><p style="font-size:70px">My Sustainability Clicker</p></h1></center>
</div>

<div style="color:#2B65EC"> 
    <div class="game-object">
        <script type="text/javascript">
           var clicks = 0;
            function updateClickCount() {
                document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML = clicks;
             if (clicks == 50) {
         alert("You have made earth sustainable!");
        } else {
            /// do something
        }

            }
        </script>
        <center><button type="button" onClick="clicks++;updateClickCount();" id="push">
           <p style="font-size:20px"><div style="color:#E238EC">Click me for Trees!</div></p></button></center>
   <center> <p style="font-size:20px"><div id="clickCount"></div></p></center>
    </div>
</div>    

<div style="color:#F70D1A">
   <center><p style="font-size:20px"><i><b>By: John Parkinham</i></b></p></center>
</div>

<center><input type="image" name="Cookie" value="Cookie" src="tree-clipart-tree_tiny_green_shaded.png" width="445px"/></center>

    </input>
```